# Remember the page after session timeout

Tags: asp.net, session, c#-4.0, session-timeout, request.querystring

In my website I want to redirect the user to the same page on which he/she was before the session timeout.

I tried it by sending the url through querystring, but it didn't work out as the url also contained "&".

My url was: `Default.aspx?FileID=23&TabID=3`.

The querystring had only `Default.aspx?FileID=23` and TabID was omitted. Is there any way I can also get it? If not with querystring, is there any other method?

Comment: are you using forms authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Session timeout try this, if using forms auth just FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage(); is enough but if you want to redirect to some other page than login use custom line below. and use Server.UrlEncode to allow & in querystring

```
     public static  void DisposeAndLogout()
            {

                HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
                try
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
                    Roles.DeleteCookie();
                    context.Session.Clear();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ErrorHandler.HandleException(ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
//or can send to some other page
                    string OriginalUrl = context.Request.RawUrl;
                    string LoginPageUrl = @"~\Login.aspx";
                    context.Response.Redirect(String.Format("{0}?ReturnUrl={1}", LoginPageUrl, context.Server.UrlEncode(OriginalUrl)));
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using FormsAuthentication:

Login:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx

Logout:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx